# Unwanted 1 second lag after click event with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, toggle, lag

I have javascript code that toggles from radio button 1 to radio button 2 when the user clicks anywhere on a box. It works, but only after a lag of 1 second or so. There will be a hundred of these boxes, so this lag really kills the user experience. Any clue where does this lag come from?

Note: if I remove the loop, and I target the elements with their unique ID's instead of looping through "all elements with class x", then the lag disappears. But I need the loop, considering there will be a hundred of those boxes...

Here is the javascript:

```
$('.checkbox-oui-non').click(function(evt) {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox-oui-non");
    var b = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox-oui-non .oui");
    var c = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox-oui-non .non");
    
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (b[i].checked ||
        c[i].checked) {
            if (b[i].checked) {
                b[i].checked = false; 
                c[i].checked = true;
            }
            else if (c[i].checked){
                b[i].checked = true; 
                c[i].checked = false;
                }
        } else {    
            b[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
});
```

and the html:

```
<div class="checkbox-oui-non">
    <span>L'enfant est né d'une précédente union</span>
    <div class="oui-non-toggle-wrapper">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" id="moi_oui" name="moi" class="oui">
            <label for="moi_oui">oui</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="moi" id="moi_non" class="non">
            <label for="moi_non">non</label>
        </div>
        <div class="oui-non-toggle"></div>
    </div><!-- end of oui-non-wrapper -->
</div><!-- end of checkbox-oui-non -->
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Only toggle the one that was clicked. Right now, every time you click on any of them, it toggles them all. You're already passing the `evt` to the function, use it.

Comment: You can actually do this without a loop at all. You can set an ID on the question, then set a click event listener on each check box via a class. When a check box is clicked you can then use jQuery to get the .parent ID of that which was clicked. You can use that ID and question clicked to create a JavaScript Object with a key, value pair. You can even use it to create a JSON object.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I tried to apply Yaakov's idea and simplified the code by removing the "else if" part as well as all the "checked = false". Now, the lag is gone when I go from "non" to "oui", great. But the lag remains when I go the other way. Half of the problem is solved.

I don't know exactly how to use the "evt" as you say. Also I'm struggling a bit as how exactly to implement Tony's solution. I'm a bit of a noob at javascript.